# Dynamic Progress Bar For Drop-Down Lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, drop-down-menu, progress-bar

I would like my page to display a progress bar that fills up as the user selects options on drop-down lists. So far I've been able to set variables to contain the value of the drop-down, and functions that alter the bar's value, but nothing that works together. Here's one of the drop-downs:

```
<select id="optionA">
    <option value=" " disabled selected>Choose One...</option>
    <option value="mike">Mike</option>
    <option value="ryce">Andrew</option>
    <option value="michael">Michael</option>
    <option value="dannyl">Danny</option>
    <option value="cozz">Cozz</option>
    <option value="drew">Andrew</option>
    <option value="pete">Pete</option>
    <option value="sean">Sean</option>
    <option value="dom">Dom</option>
    <option value="marc">Marc</option>
    <option value="lou">Lou</option>
    <option value="rob">Rob</option>
    </select>
```

For now there are two identical drop-downs, so it's id="optionA" and id="optionB". And here's the script I've tried:

```
var optAVal; 
var optBVal; 

$('#optA').on('change', function() {
    var optAVal = this.value;  
}); 

$('#optB').on('change', function() {
    var optBVal = this.value;
}); 

if (optAVal == " " && optBVal == " ") {
    $("#progressBar").attr('value','0')
;} 

if (optAVal !== " " || optBVal !== " ") {
    $("#progressBar").attr('value','50');
}

if (optAVal !-- " " && optBVal !== " ") {
    $("#progressBar").attr('value','100');
}
```

You can see the idea is that if neither have selections, the bar reads 0, if one or the other are selected, it reads 50, and if both are selected it reads 100, problem is nothing's working properly. I've tried a few different combinations, including nesting the if statements in $('#optX').on('change', function() {}); and this current combination sets the progress bar to 100% on load. Appreciate the help in advance. Thanks!!!

Comment: where is optA and progressBar?

Comment: you have optionA as id but you used optA

Comment: You're right, good catch, but that was just a typo. My fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The essential problem, in addition to small errors and typos, is that your conditionals are never called after the initial load. Thus the progress bar never gets updated.

If you use html like this:

```
<select id="optionA">
    <option value=" " disabled selected>Choose One...</option>
    <option value="mike">Mike</option>
    ...
</select>
<select id="optionB">
    <option value=" " disabled selected>Choose One...</option>=
    <option value="rob">Rob</option>
    ...
</select>
<progress id='progressBar' max='100' value='0'></progress>
```

And JQuery like this:

```
var doneA = false;
$('#optionA').on('change', function() {
    if (!doneA) {
        $("#progressBar").attr('value', $("#progressBar").prop('value')+50);
        doneA = true;
    }
}); 

var doneB = false;
$('#optionB').on('change', function() {
    if (!doneB) {
        $("#progressBar").prop('value', $("#progressBar").attr('value')+50);
        doneB = true;
    }
});
```

The result should be as you desire. Here's a working JSFiddle to verify: http://jsfiddle.net/wLt4z/2/

---

**Edit 1:** If you want to be more clever, you could assign each form option a shared class, like `class='formOption'`, and craft a generic bit of JQuery to update the progress bar appropriately. For example:

```
$('.formOption').data("done", false);
$('.formOption').on('change', function() {
    if (!$(this).data("done")) {
        $("#progressBar").attr('value', $("#progressBar").prop('value')+100/$('.formOption').length);
    $(this).data("done", true);
    }
});
```

---

**Edit 2:** Updated to ensure altering a value doesn't increased the completion percentage. In both cases, this is done by means of a simple boolean flag, which in fact supersedes checking the value.

Comment: Michael, thanks again for your answer. I did notice one small issue though: I only want this to happen one time for each drop down. The idea being a sort of "you've completed step one and then step two, great!" kind of thing. 

With your code, if you open up either drop down and select an option, and then open it again and select a new option, the bar continues to fill up. Is there something akin to a .on('firstchange', ...) or something to that effect? 

Thanks!!

Comment: Sorry about that. I goofed. There's nothing like firstchange (see http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/events.shtml for a list of events), but you can make it work with a simple boolean flag. See the changes I made to the answer.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks again, Michael. 

Just FYI, for some reason I had to switch the order of the .attr and .prop to match each other, otherwise the bar would fill completely when you choose the second value (I only want them going 25% each, as there will be two more drop downs to select).