# Dropdown box mixed with progress bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having trouble with this piece of code and was wondering if anyone could help!

The goal is to make it so that when i click on the dropdown box and click one of the options, it will move the progress bar a certain amount (Move it a different amount for each different option).

Additionally, I put two of the drop down boxes that I need. The REAL end goal is to make it so when I click on one of the options in the first dropdown box it moves the progress bar, and when I click on another option in the second box, it either adds to the progress bar or subtracts from the progress bar depending on which option you picked and which value that option had.

Cheers!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">


<div class="progressbar">
  <h2>Dynamic Progress Bar</h2>

  <div class="w3-light-grey">
    <div id="myBar" class="w3-green" style="height:24px;width:0"></div>
  </div>
  <br>

  
</div>

<script>
function changeFunc($i) {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");   
  var width = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
  function frame() {
    if (width >= 12.5) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++; 
      elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
    }
  }
}
</script>
<body>

<div id="criticalSecurityControlForms">

   <form action="/action_page.php">
      <select name="firstQ" onchange="changeFunc(value);" class="whiteselected">
          <option class="whiteselected" selected="selected">Select an Implementation</option>
         <option class="Not" value="0">Not Implemented</option>
         <option class="ImplementedOnSome" value="4">Implemented on Some Systems</option>
         <option class="All" value="8">Implemented on All Systems</option>
         <option class="AllAndAuto" value="12.5">Implemented and Automated on All Systems</option> 
      </select>
   </form>

</div>

<div id="criticalSecurityControlForms">

   <form action="/action_page.php">
      <select name="firstQ" onchange="changeFunc(value);" class="whiteselected">
          <option class="whiteselected" selected="selected">Select an Implementation</option>
         <option class="Not" value="0">Not Implemented</option>
         <option class="ImplementedOnSome" value="4">Implemented on Some Systems</option>
         <option class="All" value="8">Implemented on All Systems</option>
         <option class="AllAndAuto" value="12.5">Implemented and Automated on All Systems</option> 
      </select>
   </form>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What behavior are you experiencing with the code as it is now? And what's wrong with it? Also, you have the same `<div>` shown twice in that code snippet - not sure if that's a copy/paste error or it's actually occurring that way in your code-base.

Comment: as I explained to kblau, the goal is for each option to have a different percent that it moves the progress bar. for example, Not Implemented should move it 4% and Implemented on all systems should move it 12.5% ect. Right now each one that I click moves it 12.5%, because of the line        (width >= 12.5) {            Also, I put the two div's there because I want the second one to add percentage to the progress bar, not move it 12.5%. so If I click implemented on both for each dropdown bar, it should move the progress bar 12.5% +12.5% which is 25%

Comment: @Mitch I added an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer.  I have edited my answer and will delete this answer as soon as my edited answer is corrected.  The edited answer did not take effect yet, because I was logged in as anonymous, when I made the edit.

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index501</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .w3-light-grey {
            color: lightgray;
            border: 5px;
        }

        .w3-green {
            color: green;
            border: 5px;
        }

        .rectangle-box {
            position: relative;
            width: 0%;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #4679BD;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //I'm mixing jquery with javascript, so you should reference jquery
        //I am wiring up status bar to first dropdown
        //BE SURE to put ID in first dropdown
        //Take out the onchange in ddl
        $(function () {
            var firstIterationWidthVal = 0;
            function changeFunc(maxWidth) {
                var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
                var width = 0;
                var id = setInterval(frame(maxWidth), 10);
                function frame(maxWidth) {
                    if (firstIterationWidthVal == 0) {
                        firstIterationWidthVal = maxWidth;
                    }
                    if (width >= firstIterationWidthVal) {
                        clearInterval(id);
                    } else {
                        firstIterationWidthVal++;
                        elem.style.width = firstIterationWidthVal + '%';
                    }
                }
            }

            $("#firstQOne").change(function () {
                switch ($("#firstQOne option:selected").text()) {
                    case "Not Implemented":
                        changeFunc(4);
                        firstIterationWidthVal = 0;
                        break;
                    case "Implemented on Some Systems":
                    case "Implemented on All Systems":
                    case "Implemented and Automated on All Systems":
                        changeFunc(12.5);
                        firstIterationWidthVal = 0;
                        break;
                }
            })
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="progressbar">
        <h2>Dynamic Progress Bar</h2>
        <div class="w3-light-grey">
            <div id="myBar" class="w3-green rectangle-box" style="height:24px;width:0%"></div>
        </div>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div id="criticalSecurityControlForms">
        <form action="/action_page.php">
            <select id="firstQOne" name="firstQ" class="whiteselected">
                <option class="whiteselected" selected="selected">Select an Implementation</option>
                <option class="Not" value="0">Not Implemented</option>
                <option class="ImplementedOnSome" value="4">Implemented on Some Systems</option>
                <option class="All" value="8">Implemented on All Systems</option>
                <option class="AllAndAuto" value="12.5">Implemented and Automated on All Systems</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
    @*<div id="criticalSecurityControlFormsTwo">
            <form action="/action_page.php">
                <select name="firstQ" onchange="changeFunc(value);" class="whiteselected">
                    <option class="whiteselected" selected="selected">Select an Implementation</option>
                    <option class="Not" value="0">Not Implemented</option>
                    <option class="ImplementedOnSome" value="4">Implemented on Some Systems</option>
                    <option class="All" value="8">Implemented on All Systems</option>
                    <option class="AllAndAuto" value="12.5">Implemented and Automated on All Systems</option>
                </select>
            </form>
        </div>*@
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: YES! thanks so much! I see what you did and was able to adjust the values. For some reason the "Notimplemented" isnt working, but im sure I will be able to figure that out :) One quick question for you,  Is there a way to add the value two drop down bars to give a NEW value for the progress bar? So if the first dropdown bar is 12, and the second one is 8, it would give me 20 for the progress bar? If you can't figure it out or dont have time dont worry about it, you have been more then helpful to me :)

Comment: @Mitch I couldn't fit my reply to you in comments, so I added another answer below

Comment: Im wondering If I could just make $("#firstQTwo") and add the value from the first dropdown box to the value of whatever they pick for the second box to move the progress bar. what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

This is in regard to your comment, about wanting to add from two dropdown lists:

```
 $("#firstQOne").change(function () {
                //add another switch to capture user event for changing ddl two
                switch ($("#firstQOne option:selected").text()) {
                    case "Not Implemented":
                        changeFunc(4);
                        firstIterationWidthVal = 0;
                        break;
                    case "Implemented on Some Systems":
                    case "Implemented on All Systems":
                    case "Implemented and Automated on All Systems":
                        //added
                        //put id = "secondOne" in the second ddl
                        //try putting a switch in a switch, or add more if statements
                        //REMOVE onchange="changeFunc(value);" from second ddl
                        if ($("#secondOne option:selected").text() == "Implemented on All Systems")
                        {
                            changeFunc(12.5 + 12.5);
                        }
                        else {
                            changeFunc(12.5);
                        }
                        firstIterationWidthVal = 0;
                        break;
                }
            })
```

Comment: Also If you could look at my other answer to the adding of the two forms, because how I have it it doesnt work. Also just so you are aware, I have 32 of these dropdown forms, and the user needs to be able to select any one of them randomly and it should do the math regardless of where they are. Thats why I am hesitant to base the firstQOne off of the firstQTwo because if the user skips these two and goes straight to the third dropdown box the math might be wrong. Im thinking if there was a way to return current value, then I could add to that. Idk if you understand what I mean, but thanks :)

Comment: I am out of town till Wednesday.  I think someone can pick up the work now, and if you need me on Wednesday, I would be glad to help.  Sounds like all we need is some simple refactoring, considering you have 32 dropdown lists.

Comment: @Mitch  I have an hour now and I will start figuring it out, even if I can't finish, and you get it working yourself.  I will read over the requirements more, but it seems you may want to create the dropdowns in a loop, and have javascript that works for everything and is refactored.  The less javascript needed the better.  Good luck.

Comment: @Mitch, two forms had worked all along for me. I put <select id = "secondOne" name="firstQ" class="whiteselected"> in the second form. (added id).  Also aligning values of options(use val()) to get eg. not implement value = 4%--would be good

Comment: Awesome, I will do my best to finish the code before Wednesday. You have been very helpful and I appreciate you taking the time to help me :)

Comment: Check this out......now im just trying to figure out how to give each option the value and have it move the progress bar based on that value 
     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23376408/dynamic-progress-bar-for-drop-down-lists/43942276?noredirect=1#comment74916962_43942276

Answer (score 0):

So Im not sure if this is the right way to do it but here it goes....

```
 $("#firstQTwo").change(function () {
            //add another switch to capture user event for changing ddl two
            switch ($("#firstQTwo option:selected").text()) {
                 case "Select an Implementation" :
                    changeFunc(0);
                    firstIterationWidthVal = 0;
                    break;
                case "Not Implemented":
                    changeFunc(0);
                    firstIterationWidthVal = 0;
                    break;
                case "Implemented on Some Systems":
                changeFunc(4);
                    firstIterationWidthVal = 0;
                    break;
                case "Implemented on All Systems":
                changeFunc(8);
                    firstIterationWidthVal = 0;
                    break;
                case "Implemented and Automated on All Systems":
                    changeFunc(12.5);
                    firstIterationWidthVal = 0;
                    break;
                    //added
                    //put id = "secondOne" in the second ddl
                    //try putting a switch in a switch, or add more if statements
                    //REMOVE onchange="changeFunc(value);" from second ddl
                    if ($("#firstQTwo option:selected").text() == 
                   "Implemented and Automated on All Systems")
                    {
                        changeFunc(12.5 + 12.5);
                    }
                      if ($("#firstQTwo option:selected").text() == 
                    "Implemented on Some Systems")
                    {
                        changeFunc(12.5 + 4);
                    }
                     if ($("#firstQTwo option:selected").text() == 
                    "Implemented on All Systems")
                    {
                        changeFunc(12.5 + 8);
                    }
                    else {
                        changeFunc(12.5);
                    }
                    firstIterationWidthVal = 0;
                    break;
            }
        })
        })
    })
</script>
```

So as it is right here it doesnt work (obviously) :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for so many answers.  This post, should help you.

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index501</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .w3-light-grey {
            color: lightgray;
            border: 5px;
        }

        .w3-green {
            color: green;
            border: 5px;
        }

        .rectangle-box {
            position: relative;
            width: 0%;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #4679BD;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //I'm mixing jquery with javascript, so you should reference jquery
        //I am wiring up status bar to first dropdown
        //BE SURE to put ID in first dropdown
        //Take out the onchange in ddl
        $(function () {
            for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
                var toAdd =
            "<div id='criticalSecurityControlForms'>" +
                "<form action='/action_page.php'>" +
                    "<select id='" + i + "QSelect' name='" + i + "QSelect' class='whiteselected'>" +
                       "<option class='NoValue' selected='selected' value='0'>Select an Implementation</option>" +
                        "<option class='Not' value='4'>Not Implemented</option>" +
                        "<option class='ImplementedOnSome' value='4'>Implemented on Some Systems</option>" +
                        "<option class='All' value='12.5'>Implemented on All Systems</option>" +
                        "<option class='AllAndAuto' value='12.5'>Implemented and Automated on All Systems</option>" +
                    "</select>" +
                "</form>" +
            "</div>"

                $("#dynamicAddSelect").append(toAdd);
            }

            var firstIterationWidthVal = 0;
            function changeFunc(maxWidth) {
                var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
                var width = 0;
                var id = setInterval(frame(maxWidth), 10);
                function frame(maxWidth) {
                    if (firstIterationWidthVal == 0) {
                        firstIterationWidthVal = maxWidth;
                    }
                    if (width >= firstIterationWidthVal) {
                        clearInterval(id);
                    } else {
                        firstIterationWidthVal++;
                        elem.style.width = firstIterationWidthVal + '%';
                    }
                }
            }

            $(".whiteselected").change(function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                //alert($this.attr("id"));  this is how to get the id
                if ($this.val() == 0) {
                    firstIterationWidthVal = 0;
                }
                changeFunc($this.val());
            })
        })
        //The following is how you can get the previous value of a dropdown list, taken from another project
        //var previousTokenAmount;
        //$("#payamtDDL").on('focus', function () {
        //    previousTokenAmount = $("#payamtDDL").val();
        //})
        //$("#payamtDDL").change(function () {
        //    var Data = {
        //        ANumber: $("#ANumberId").val(),
        //        Pay: $("#payamtDDL").val()
        //    }
        //    $.ajax({
        //        url: '/Ajax/AjaxIntoServer',
        //        type: 'POST',
        //        data: Data,
        //        dataType: 'json',
        //        success: function (result) {
        //            if (result.IsDataTrue) {
        //                if (!confirm("Ok or Cancel")) {
        //                    $("#payamtDDL").val(previousTokenAmount);
        //                }
        //            }
        //        },
        //        error: function (data, status, error) {
        //            //alert("error");
        //        }
        //    });
        //})

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="progressbar">
        <h2></h2>
        <div class="w3-light-grey">
            <div id="myBar" class="w3-green rectangle-box" style="height:24px;width:0%"></div>
        </div>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div id="dynamicAddSelect" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I have ditched the dropdown bar as I realise it is much harder to use then say a radio option. This is the code im using now as a test, the only problem with it so far is that if i click a different button, it adds to the existing value of the progress bar. This is great, the only problem is that if I click a different radio option in the same form it should either subtract or add to the progress bar. right now it keeps adding to it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>testinggg</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="AuditScriptAssesmentToolTest.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>



</head>
<body>

<form action="">
  <input id="selectA" type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
  <input id="selectB" type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
  <input id="selectC" type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other
</form>

<br>

<form action="">
  <input id="selectD" type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
  <input id="selectE" type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
  <input id="selectF" type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other
</form>

<progress id='progressBar' max='100' value='0'></progress>

<script>

  var doneA = false;
$('#selectA').on('click', function() {
    if (!doneA) {
        $("#progressBar").attr('value', $("#progressBar").prop('value')+10);
        doneA = true;
    }
}); 

var doneB = false;
$('#selectB').on('click', function() {
    if (!doneB) {
        $("#progressBar").attr('value', $("#progressBar").prop('value')+20);
        doneB = true;
   } 
});

var doneC = false;
$('#selectC').on('click', function() {
    if (!doneC) {
        $("#progressBar").attr('value', $("#progressBar").prop('value')+30);
        doneC = true;
    }
});

  var doneD = false;
$('#selectD').on('click', function() {
    if (!doneD) {
        $("#progressBar").attr('value', $("#progressBar").prop('value')+5);
        doneD = true;
    }
}); 

var doneE = false;
$('#selectE').on('click', function() {
    if (!doneE) {
        $("#progressBar").attr('value', $("#progressBar").prop('value')+10);
        doneE = true;
   } 
});

var doneF = false;
$('#selectF').on('click', function() {
    if (!doneF) {
        $("#progressBar").attr('value', $("#progressBar").prop('value')+15);
        doneF = true;
    }
});
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```